# Optimise For Best Appearance Option Breaks User Forms

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am having the following problem: my client updated Excel version and all user forms appear to be broken. (Described here: [Excel UserForm displays at the wrong size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51527944/excel-userform-displays-at-the-wrong-size))

There is a special default setting "Optimize for best appearance" (When using multiple displays) in newer Excel versions that causes the problem. When I switch to "Optimize for compatibility" option, the problem is gone.

[image]

**Question:** did someone figure out how to change this setting programmatically (in VBA code)?

I tried to record the macro and change the settings but no luck. The resulting program is empty.

Comment: That's Word that your showing, not Excel.

Comment: @freeflow true! But it is exactly the same in excel. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not manage to find a workaround. Apparently when the "optimise for best appearance" option is active and multiple monitors are connected to a device, excel cannot properly build buttons, objects etc. Telling each user not to use multiple monitors or to switch this option manually off is not an option.

I am changing right now the application in the way that I do not use any objects. It sucks but there is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

Well you could try to change the registry settings:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options\RenderForMonitorDpi
```

Doing something like ([Source](https://www.vbarchiv.net/tipps/tipp_907-registry-lesen-und-schreiben-ohne-api.html)):

```
Public Function RegWrite(ByVal Path As String, _
  ByVal Value As String, _
  Optional ByVal Typ As String = "REG_SZ") As Boolean
 
  Dim ws As Object
 
  On Error Goto ErrHandler
  Set ws = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  ws.RegWrite Path, Value, Typ
  RegWrite = True
  Exit Function
 
ErrHandler:
  RegWrite = False
End Function
```

However it did not work for me. It changes the registry value but after the restart excel won't change the setting and will change the registry value back to the old value.

Comment: Indeed, you cannot change Excel registry settings while it is running, it caches them and then resets them.  Very annoying for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I suppose there is always SendKeys to change the display option.  :(

There was a time when COM/VBA was important and all options have Application.* properties, but sadly not any more.